# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione este código (php)?

Tags: php, html

Es un programa de `php` en el que se usan formularios. Debe calcular la potencia de un número, ingresando la base y el exponente usando `for`.

La verdad no he entendido muy bien las explicaciones del profesor, sobre todo lo de las funciones.

Sé que los códigos tienen muchos errores, lo que necesito es ayuda para construir uno que funcione con las características anteriormente mencionadas.

Si me pudieran dar alguna explicación les agradeceré mucho.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form action="potenciaDos.php" method="post">
    <div>
      Introduzca la base:
      <input type="text" name="base">
    </div>
    <div>
      Introduzca la potencia
      <input type="text" name="exp">
      <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
    </div>
    <?php
      function potencia ($b,$e){
        $b=$_POST['base'];
        $e=$_POST['exp'];
        $p=1;
        for ($x=1; $x<=$e; $x++){
          $p=$p*$b;
        }
      }
    ?>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
  echo "El resultado es: ".$_POST["potencia"]
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Con el código que se visualiza no veo de donde sale la variable "potencia". También fíjate si los parámetros que estas pasando a la función potencia() son correctos. Veo que hay una confusión con los parámetros y los valores de las variables de esa función.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer archivo, suponiendo que se llama **potenciaUno.php**, recoges los datos en un formulario y al presionar el botón de tipo `submit`, se envían los datos al archivo **potenciaDos.php**...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="potenciaDos.php" method="post">
            <div>
                Introduzca la base: <input type="text" name="base">
            </div>
            <div>
                Introduzca el exponente <input type="text" name="exp">
                <Input type="submit" value="aceptar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Luego, en el archivo **potenciaDos.php**, recibes los datos que enviaste por `post`, haces la operación con el ciclo `for` e imprimes el resultado en pantalla.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      //Recoger los valores recibidos por post y enviarlos como parámetros a la función
      $b = $_POST['base'];
      $e = $_POST['exp'];

      //Ejecutar la función potencia pasándole como argumentos la base y el exponente
      $potencia = potencia($b, $e);

      //Mostrar en pantalla el resultado de toda la operación.
      echo "El resultado es: ".$potencia;

      //Declarar la función y recibir los parámetros base y exponente
      function potencia($b, $e){
        //Inicializar la variable para calcular la potencia
        $p = 1;
        //Calcular la potencia
        for ($x=1; $x<=$e; $x++){
          $p = $b * $p;
        }
        //Devolver el resultado final
        return $p;
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Acá te dejo [un buen recurso](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/312.php) para aprender sobre funciones en `php`.